# How to normalize HSV values. Python

Tags: python, opencv, hsv

I'm trying to get boundaries of some colors. I used GIMP to get lower and upper boundaries.

From OpenCV documentation I read the next:

'For HSV, Hue range is [0,179], Saturation range is [0,255] and Value range is [0,255]. Different softwares use different scales. So if you are comparing OpenCV values with them, you need to normalize these ranges'

So, I'm trying to normalize those ranges to compare them with GIMP. This is the code:

```
# z = (xi  - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
# where x=(x1,...,xn) and zi is now your i normalized data.

def norm_H_value(h):
        return (h - 0) / (179 - 0)

def norm_SV_values(x):
    return (x-0) / (255 - 0)
```

I'm not really sure if this is the right way to normalize these ranges, so, if you can help me or give some advice, that would be great.

Comment: What ranges does GIMP use?

Comment: @DanMašek H[0, 360], S[0, 100], V[0, 100]

Answer (score 3):

Use the following equations to convert from GIMP HSV values to OpenCV ones

GIMP values range:
H: 0 -> 360, S: 0 -> 100, V: 0 -> 100

OpenCV values range:
H: 0 -> 180, S: 0 -> 255, V: 0 -> 255

```
opencv_H = (gimp_H / 360) * 180; // (gimp_H / 2)
opencv_S = (gimp_S / 100) * 255;
opencv_V = (gimp_V / 100) * 255;
```